# Can we get shares an reactions in the response from an instagram story via webhook/api?

Tags: instagram, google-cloud-pubsub, ngrok, facebook-webhooks, instagram-story

I am trying to setup a webhook to my cloudrun and pubsub service.
Is there anyway in which i can get to see reactions and shares of my stories; The sample response does not seem to have a key value for the same.. Any suggestions ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSFNX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Instagram API has Reactions metric available yet. At least i could not find mentions to it on documentation.
I was able to find reactions info only on Facebook APIs. Maybe it still is a work in progress for Instagram.
( reactions are not event returned as metrics on story_insights ).

Unless reactions are considered on Instagram API as comments, there is no way to trigger Webhooks on reactions.

References:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/instagram/#story_insights
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/instagram/#comments